# In PHP 7.0 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function json_encode()

Tags: php, json, nginx, fatal-error, php-7

My server configurations:

```
[root@server ~]# php -v 
PHP 7.0.22 (cli) (built: Aug 7 2017 16:18:27) ( NTS ) 

[root@server ~]# nginx -v 
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
```

OS: CentOS 7.3.1611 (Core)

Details of my YUM installation:

```
[root@server ~]# yum list installed | grep php
php70u-cli.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-common.x86_64                    7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-fpm.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-fpm-nginx.noarch                 7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-mysqlnd.x86_64                   7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-pdo.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius
```

Here is the details of the investigation:
I tried executing following code in test.php:

Here are my system details:
PHP Version => 7.0.22
OS: 
I am trying to execute following code in test2.php:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

And, getting the following error:

```
[root@server ~]# php /tmp/test2.php
**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function json_encode() in /tmp/test2.php:3**
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I run the following command to install json for php7 and it worked perfectly fine.

```
[root@server dbs]# sudo yum install php70u-json
```

Comment: If you're a Fedora 22+ user, the command line is:


#sudo dnf install php-json

Answer (score 5):

For me was enough with:

```
 yum install php-json
```

I'm using php7.2

Answer (score 2):

Install:

```
  php70u-json.x86_64 0:7.0.32-1.ius.centos7
```

Result:

```
Complete!
[root@server1 ~]# systemctl restart httpd
```